# Focus after closing Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

It appears that the default behavior of `Bootstraps` `modal` is to focus in on the link used to open the `modal` when you close it.

I'm trying to take the focus away from the link I click to open the `modal` when I close it. it doesn't have to focus on anything specific, just not the opening link.

My code so far seems to be doing nothing:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $('.close').on("click", function() {
            $("#profile").blur();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code attaches an event listener to the element with class `.close` when the modal is hidden rather than executing the `$("#profile").blur();` line.

You can just do

```
 $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
     $("#profile").blur();
 });
```

Comment: What is happening then? Is the blur method fired? You may want to add the code in a document ready wrap if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Yes it is fired and I have the code wrapped in  document.ready

Comment: The code is working now I had the  <a> associated with a class and for some reason that was preventing it, thank you for your help :)